# Why are consecutive vowels skipped?

Tags: javascript, arrays, switch-statement

I have the following JS function that removes vowels from a string and outputs it to console.

For input string "quickbrownfox" the function skips consecutive u and i vowels can someone point out the error in logic.

```js
function vowels(s) {
  var arr = [...s];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var x = arr[i];
    switch (x) {
      case 'a':
      case 'e':
      case 'i':
      case 'o':
      case 'u':
        var out = arr.splice(i, 1);
        console.log(out[0]);
    }
  }
}
  vowels("quickbrownfox")
```

Comment: When you splice a character out, you change the effective meaning of the index (`i`).  If you subtract 1 from `i` when you find each vowel, it'll work.

Comment: Or take a copy of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two characters are all you need to fix this function
Change this:

```js
var out = arr.splice(i, 1);
```

to this:

```js
var out = arr.splice(i--, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't splice the array, just log the value directly.

```js
function vowels(s) {
  var arr = [...s];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var x = arr[i];
    switch (x) {
      case 'a':
      case 'e':
      case 'i':
      case 'o':
      case 'u':
        // var out = arr.splice(i, 1);
        console.log(arr[i]);
    }
  }
}
  vowels("quickbrownfox")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your splice is mutating the array which messes up the loop

Instead just filter it

```js
const vowels = "aeiou"
const getVowels = s => [...s].filter(letter => vowels.includes(letter))
console.log(
  getVowels("quickbrownfox")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `var out = arr.splice(i, 1);`

```js
function vowels(s) {
var arr=[...s];
for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++)
{
    var x=arr[i];
    switch(x)
    {
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
            console.log(x);
    }
}
}
console.log(vowels('quickbrownfox'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over `s` instead of `arr` and also assigne `var x = s[i]` instead of `var x = arr[i]`